# How to return object if it contains a letter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I'm racking my brain here and need some quick help.

I have the following JSON object:

```
"product": {
    "diagnostics": null,
        "skus": [{
            "itemCode": "Q28988",
            "salesCode": "Q2898800",
            "listPrice": 22,
            "salePrice": 22,
            "numberOfBottles": 1,
            "salePricePerBottle": 22,
            "id": "esku580806",
            "vppApplier": false,
            "vppPrice": null,
            "vppDiscountPct": null
        }, {
            "itemCode": "C28988",
            "salesCode": "C2898800",
            "listPrice": 264,
            "salePrice": 264,
            "numberOfBottles": 12,
            "salePricePerBottle": 22,
            "id": "esku580811",
            "vppApplier": false,
            "vppPrice": null,
            "vppDiscountPct": null
        }],
            "id": "eprod440905",
}
```

And I need to filter the skus array and only return itemCodes that begin with the letter 'Q'. I'm using underscore and JavaScript, and this is the closest I could get, but it doesnt seem to return anything.

```
var codes = _.filter($scope.cb.recommendations, function(obj){
            var startLetter = obj.product.skus.slice(); 
            return startLetter[0] === 'Q';
        });
```

$scope.cb.recommendations is the JSON object - snippet is above. Big thanks!

Comment: Don't you want to look at the "itemCode" field, and not just the array of SKU objects?

Comment: Yes, I do - but wasnt sure how to do that? Is it? obj.product.skus[].itemCode - but that seems to fail

Comment: What is `$scope.cb.recommendations`? Seems like you'd want to be filtering `obj.product.skus`. Do you want the result to be those sku elements that have an `itemCode` that starts with a 'Q', or do you want an array of item codes?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. If a single product can have lots of SKUs, do you want to return that product if *any* SKU has an item code that starts with "Q"?

Comment: There will only ever be one sku starting with Q, so I just want to return that one without having to know the whole itemCode. So I would assume that would be a filter or search.

Comment: Yes Pointy - that's exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: @jrutter, you are looping through recommendations. Next you have to loop through the obj.product.skus as it's an array. When inside that loop, you have to check the ```skuVariable.itemCode.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === 'q'``` 

The last or first thing to take into consideration is do you want  a list of itemCode objects or strings?

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @cbayram - Thank you so much, I think I've figure it out just about! Have a great day! Your tip helped me!

Comment: @jrutter, good stuff. Check out the ```_.find``` function for getting the first truthy match. Say with an outer ```_.each``` loop you can ```return false``` to prematurely break out of it once find returns a match in your inner loop. Perhaps post your solution as an answer and/or pick one of the fine answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain what `$scope.cb.recommendations` is, so I'll show how to filter just the `skus` array for one product. The trick is to pass a third argument to `_.filter` which gets bound to `this` inside the predicate function:

```
var codes = [];
_.filter(
    obj.product.skus,
    function(sku) {
        if (sku.itemCode[0] === 'Q') {
            this.push(sku.itemCode);
        }
    },
    codes
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without underscore and if only 1 'Q-item' may exist:

```
function findQ(skus) {
  var len = skus.length; 
  while(len--) {
    if(skus[len].itemCode.indexOf('Q') === 0) 
        return skus[len];
  }
}

var item = findQ(json.product.skus);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8pb13cdj/